# how do I create a message client as a singleton in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, signalr, signalr.client

The workflow is something like this:

- user submits some kind of request
- server responds *right away* with a "yea, got your request, will work on it"
- user is informed that the server is working on it
- when the server finishes, it tells the signalr hub: hey i finished "this task" for "this guy"
- the hub forwards the message to the angularjs client
- the client broadcasts the message out

now if the user is still on the same view

- controller for view handles the message, and the scope is updated

otherwise, the user wanted to do something else, navigated away from page, etc..

- nothing is listening for the message, so its dropped

An example exists here
http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com/2013/05/ImplementingSignalRStockTickerUsingAngularJSPart1.html

Asking some people in the IRC for angular, and they didn't particularly like how the client is created in the initialize, or that its in a factory, or that callbacks are forwarded into the factory.

Some of the feedback included something about app.run, or a service, and broadcasting the events, all very vague.

How should I be implementing something like this? I had initially thought that a service returning a singleton is good, but apparently not? Seems like there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I created a lib called SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy just for cases like these

Install using nuget

```
Install-Package SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
```

Check wiki for how to set it up
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Once set up all you need todo to get it to listen to a back end event from javascript is

Below code is Knockoutjs MVVM, but can easily be changed to angular MVC like code

```
ViewModel = function() {
   signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyApp.Events.TestEvent, this.onTestEvent, this);
};

ViewModel.prototype = {
    onTestEvent: function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't really have any issues with the server side, as a matter of fact, all of that is already done. What I'm wondering is how do I setup the jquery client as a singleton in angular so that it can actually receive the messages from the hub, (since the clientid changes with each page transition if its not a singleton)

Comment: Its a SPA right? If not you cant make a singleton of it. My above code is a nicer way of getting what you want thats why I posted it

Comment: yes, it is, what i'm saying is I want to know the technical details of *how* I **should** have the client written, as in should it be in a service? created at app.run? etc...

Comment: You can check out here how I did https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.eventAggregator.js Basicly its a singleton, but it also abstracts away the hub stuff etc

Answer (score 0):

Every time you navigate to a new webpage everything is loaded again: CSS, JS scripts, and a new SignalR connection is created.

Here is a [demo](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/05/21/datatable-using-signalr-angularjs-entityframework.aspx) of using SignalR+AngularJS together

Comment: That's not true, I've specifically added an angularjs tag to my question and angularjs is in the subject. please read up on SPAs before posting something like that. As a matter of fact, I've just gotten the whole thing working, its a singleton, navigation between pages work, and the ID is the same throughout, unless they hit f5.

Comment: Did you use the same approach as you mentioned in the question? I mean, a service, a run block and events to notify once the connection is started. Let me know some details so that I can update the blog post :)